# What are the parameters for the search method of the Tire gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I need to run a search using Tire with my query specifically defined as a parameter, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

```
search = {
  query: {
    function_score: {
      query: { match_all: {} },
      # filters is an array previously built
      functions: filters,
      score_mode: "total"
    }
  }
}

Program.tire.search(load: true, size: 50, search)
```

I'm receiving the following error: `/Users/app/models/program_match.rb:122: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting tASSOC` which makes me believe I'm simply missing a key word before I call `search`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>You probably just need to do:</s>

```
Program.tire.search({load: true, size: 50}.merge(search))
```

**EDIT**

Actually, looking at the source for `search` (https://github.com/karmi/retire/blob/master/lib/tire/model/search.rb), it looks like you need to do:

```
Program.tire.search(search, {load: true, size: 50})
```

`search` expects two params (query, options) or one param (for options) and a block (for the query). Ruby gets confused because you have started a hash (`load: true ...`) and then just put a new hash (your `search` hash), which it sees as a hash key (with no value).

Also, if you are just starting out with Tire, I would suggest checking out [elasticsearch-rails](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails), which, according to the author, is replacing Tire.

I recently converted a Tire project to elasticsearch-rails, and have found that it can do everything Tire does, although it doesn't provide the query DSL (it seems like you're not using that anyway, so no loss).

**EDIT 2**

You can do a simple `match_all` query like:

```
Program.tire.search(load: true, size: 50) { query { all } }
```

You can get something similar by doing:

```
Program.tire.search('*', load: true, size: 50)
```

As I noted in a comment below, a query as the first param for `search` will always be wrapped in a `query_string` query.

Probably the best way to do what you asked initially is to do:

```
Tire.search(Video.tire.index_name, query: {
  function_score: {
    query: { match_all: {} },
    functions: filters,
    score_mode: "total"
  }
}).results
```

I just tested a similar `function_score` query on a local project and confirmed that it produces the expected query.

**EDIT 3**

I've never used the `load` option before, but it looks like you can do:

```
Tire.search(Video.tire.index_name, payload: {
  query: {
    function_score: {
      query: { match_all: {} },
      functions: filters,
      score_mode: "total"
    }
  }
}, load: true).results
```

Note that you have to wrap the query as the value for `payload`.

Comment: @kardiez Hi, thanks for the response, it makes complete sense, although I receive [this](http://pastebin.com/b034sGx0) error. Could there be something wrong with my search block? I'd love to migrate over from Tire, but I've yet to find a good doc for how to do it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @XMLSlayer, apparently the `search` function wraps the query hash within `{query: query_string: {} }` (see about l. 99 of `lib/tire/model/search.rb`). See some discussion about using `function_score` here (https://github.com/karmi/retire/issues/874), which provides a workaround.

Comment: Yeah, there doesn't seem to be a good guide for transitioning, but the two libraries are very similar. A good chunk of the change involves just using `__elasticsearch__` instead of `tire` to identify the ES proxy object.

Comment: @kardiez, Okay that wrapping makes more sense. Yes I've stumbled across that link as well, but #{Tire::Model::Search.index_prefix} returns `nil` for me, so this piece of code does nothing besides search for the string "_ideas"

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what the commenter is trying to do with that line. However, I think you just need to specify the model index name there so you should be able to replace `"#{Tire::Model::Search.index_prefix}_ideas"` with `Program.tire.index_name`.

Comment: @kardiez, Hi, so I've gone through and gotten rid of all the fancy types of queries and it's simply running a `query {match_all{}}` currently, and I'm still getting the same errors. I'm no longer dependent on new syntax, but I still can't manage to get my query to run inside the `search` method. Any ideas?

Comment: @XMLSlayer, I added some info to my answer.

Comment: @kardiez, that's phenomenal, thank you so much. Last question, I'm assuming `.results` does a similar thing `load: true` did originally. If I need the results to be in the same format as they were originally, where would I put `load: true`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55872/discussion-between-xml-slayer-and-kardeiz).